# Form causing link not to function properly?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm working on an eCommerce site that has some uneditable HTML. One of the features they provide is a "quick" add to cart button, where when you click it, you remain on your page but a little mini window pop ups showing the contents of your cart, including the item you just added. I wrote a little script that adds this quick add link to all the products when displayed in a category list of products, but when you click this link it sends you to the actual cart page without bringing up the mini window.

I THINK this is happening because it is within a form. I could be wrong, but that is the only thing I can think of why its happening. The relevent HTML:

```
<form class="search_results_section" method="post" name="MainForm" id="MainForm" action="/searchresults.asp" onsubmit="return OnSubmitSearchForm(event, this);">
   <!-- other stuff -->
      <a class="addit" href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=BBB-DWCB">Add To Cart</a>
   <!-- other stuff -->
</form>

<a class="addit" href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=BBB-DWCB">Add To Cart</a>
```

The two a links are exactly the same, but when I click the one on the bottom outside of the form, it does what I want, which is keeps you on the page but opens up the mini cart window. The one within the form, on the products themselves, are taking me to a different page. Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be happening, or what I can do to fix it?

One thing I've tried (but doesn't work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $form = $('form[action="/searchresults.asp"]');
   $form.submit(function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            //
      },'json');
      return false;
   });
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us the code which binds the events to the links?

Comment: Agree with ComFreek, there must a JavaScript event bound to that hyperlink. Please locate the `.on()` or `.bind()` event by searching the  name of the function that opens the popup.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how they do it, or what events are binding. But I've just searched through the code and have now edited my question with links to the js files that I THINK they are in. I've already searched for ".on" and ".bind" with no luck, but maybe you will know better than I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is something like this

```
<form class="search_results_section" method="post" name="MainForm" id="MainForm" action="/searchresults.asp" onsubmit="return OnSubmitSearchForm(event, this);">
```

Remove `onsubmit="return OnSubmitSearchForm(event, this);` and use following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#MainForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            console.log(response)
      },'json'); // you suppose to return json from the server
    });
});
```

Since you have an id in the form (`MainForm`) so it's better to use it this way and in the code `e.preventDefault();`, which prevents the default behaviour of form submit (stops submission).

**Update:**

Also, in the form, you have an `a` tag like

```
<a class="addit" href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=BBB-DWCB">Add To Cart</a>
```

Use a `button/submit` instead, this is the main problem in your code that navigating to another page instead of form submission. Make your form look something like

```
<form class="search_results_section" method="post" name="MainForm" id="MainForm" action="/searchresults.asp">
    <!-- other stuff -->

    <input type="submit" class="addit" name="btn_sub"  />
</form>
```

**Update:**

If you can't edit the form and need to use the `<a>` tag instead of a `submit` button then you have to bind the handler to the click event of that link, something like

```
$('#MainForm a.addit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr('href')+'&'+$(this).closest('form').serialize(), function(response){
        console.log(response)
    },'json');
});
```

And, on the server side, get the values from `$_GET` array because, you are using `params` with your url in the `<a>` tag (`href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=BBB-DWCB"`), so just add the serialized form data to the end of the current `url` and avoid `post` (if not necessary). So, your `url` will finally look something like

```
/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=BBB-DWCB&forminput1=value1&forminput2=value2
```

because of this code

```
$(this).attr('href')+'&'+$(this).closest('form').serialize()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, all the form stuff is uneditable, unless there's a way I could do it with jQuery?

Comment: The site is using Volusion, the eCommerce service. Much of the code they have for their sites is auto generated and directly uneditable, but I could use JavaScript. No PHP however.

Comment: Your last edit seems to have solved the problem, mostly. It now adds it to the cart without redirecting you, but it doesn't cause the mini pop up to appear. This is fine though, both because I actually have no idea what function calls it, but I can easily create some other notification. Also, the "&forminput1=value1&forminput2=value2" seems to be unnecessary, as it still works with just the jQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're submitting the form back to itself, you don't need to specify an action:

```
<form name="MyForm" method="post" action="" ...>
```